# Unable to validate only space in email validation by using [EmailAddress] annotation

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using `[EmailAddress] data annotation` to validate email address. I've noticed that if I add space than it is not working. It works fine if I use period, hyphen, underscore but space.

**Model:**

```
[DisplayName(@"Custom Email Confirmation Address")]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = @"Invalid Email Address")]
public string CustomEmailConfirmationAddress { get; set; }
```

**Custom Control:**

```
<div>
    <%=Html.RequiredLabelFor(m => m.CustomEmailConfirmationAddress) %>
    <%=Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomEmailConfirmationAddress, new { maxlength = 100 })%>
    <%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CustomEmailConfirmationAddress)%>
</div>
```

**On Browser: For space `class="textboxhelp-focus valid"`**

```
<div>
    <label class="required" for="CustomEmailConfirmationAddress">Custom Email Confirmation Address</label>
    <input id="CustomEmailConfirmationAddress" class="textboxhelp-focus valid" type="text" value="" name="CustomEmailConfirmationAddress" maxlength="100" data-val-email="Invalid Email Address" data-val="true" help="noreply@example.com" style="width: 300px;">
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="CustomEmailConfirmationAddress"></span>
</div>
```

[image]

**For Underscore: `class="textboxhelp-focus input-validation-error"`**

```
<div>
    <label class="required" for="CustomEmailConfirmationAddress">Custom Email Confirmation Address</label>
    <input id="CustomEmailConfirmationAddress" class="textboxhelp-focus input-validation-error" type="text" value="" name="CustomEmailConfirmationAddress" maxlength="100" data-val-email="Invalid Email Address" data-val="true" help="noreply@example.com" style="width: 300px;">
    <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="CustomEmailConfirmationAddress">
</div>
```

[image]

Am I missing something here?

Comment: A space is the equivalent of `null` so you would need a `RequiredAttribute` to validate a space

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for suggestions. What I did is, simply do not allow space on the field which can pretty much fix my issue.